# Kate Equivalent Of Go To File In Textmate

Tags: ubuntu, textmate, kate

Is there an equivalent of Textmate's Go To File in Kate?
kate is a really nice editor and this is the one functionality that would make kate all taht I need as my text editor

Thanks!

Comment: Some feedback would be nice ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what "Go to file" actually means.

1. Switch between already opened files:
   `Alt-Left` or `Alt-Right` to go back/forward one file in the document tree.
2. Open file in the same directory:
   `Strg-O` opens the "File open" dialog with the directory, where the current document is in.
3. Use the file system browser on the left panel

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are looking for `Quick Open`, which is bound to the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+O` by default. If this does not work for you, your Kate version is too old and you first have to enable the Quick Open plugin to get this functionality.

You may also be interested in the [Projects Plugin](http://kate-editor.org/2012/11/02/using-the-projects-plugin-in-kate/), which extends Quick Open quite nicely.